# Amazon Redshift ERROR: XX000: Manifest file is not in correct json format . Please tell me where is wrong

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

The following error occurred,When using the COPY command to load Amazon Redshift with a manifest.

```
ERROR: XX000: Manifest file is not in correct json format
```

I think json text of manifestfile is wrong, but i'm not sure where is wrong.

copy command detail is follows:

・create table command

```
enter code here
CREATE TABLE mddb.test
(
    parent INTEGER ENCODE lzo,
    parentname VARCHAR(100) ENCODE lzo,
    child INTEGER ENCODE lzo,
    childname VARCHAR(100) ENCODE lzo
)
DISTSTYLE EVEN;
```

・S3Directory

```
217444159777-japan-manufacturing-data
   |
   ----testmani.manifest
   |
   ----abcd----CopyCommadTest.csv
   |
   ----efgh----CopyCommadTest.csv
```

・CSV file

```
parentid    parentname  childid childname
3   kenta   4   kentachild
```

・manifestfile

```
{
  "entries": [
    {
      "url": "s3://217444159777-japan-manufacturing-data/abcd/CopyCommadTest.csv",
      "mandatory": true
    },
    {
      "url": "s3://217444159777-japan-manufacturing-data/efgh/CopyCommadTest.csv",
      "mandatory": true
    }
  ]
}
```

・LoadCommand

```
COPY mddb.test
FROM 's3://217444159777-japan-manufacturing-data/testmani.manifest' 
CREDENTIALS 'aws_iam_role=arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxx'
MANIFEST
DELIMITER '\t' 
ACCEPTANYDATE 
IGNOREHEADER as 1 
IGNOREBLANKLINES 
FILLRECORD 
TRIMBLANKS 
BLANKSASNULL 
DATEFORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD' 
TIMEFORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS' 
null as '\0' -
MAXERROR 10
```

I was successful the following command:

```
COPY mddb.test
FROM 's3://217444159777-japan-manufacturing-data/abcd/CopyCommadTest.csv' 
CREDENTIALS 'aws_iam_role=arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxx'
DELIMITER '\t'
ACCEPTANYDATE 
IGNOREHEADER as 1 
IGNOREBLANKLINES 
FILLRECORD 
TRIMBLANKS 
EMPTYASNULL 
BLANKSASNULL 
DATEFORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD' 
TIMEFORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS' 
null as '\0' 
MAXERROR 10
```

Please tell me where is wrong.

Comment: manifest looks ok - check permissions on that? otherwise i think this might be one for AWS support to look at.

Comment: I have allowed the following permissions
AmazonS3FullAccess
AWSGlueConsoleFullAccess

Is this not enough ?

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same error and l was able to fix it 
Note 1. The file is a text file but in a json format, its not a json file.
Filename -> manifest and saved as .txt

```
{
    "entries": [
      {"url":"s3://redshiftcontainer/testdt/Book3.txt","mandatory":true}
    ]
}
```

In redshift query:
    copy book2
    from 's3://redshiftcontainer/manifest/manifest.txt' 
    iam_role 'arn:aws:iam:::role/RedshiftRole'
    delimiter ','
    manifest;